# Docker host on AWS cannot wget

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, networking, wget

I am unable to connect to nexus from my docker host.

Steps:

1. I installed docker on AWS linux and created an image.
2. I then launched an instance based out of the image.
3. I log on to the instance ( docker host)  and docker is running
4. I try a wget on the host to get a file from nexus and I get the following

Error:

`Resolving nexus.XXXX.com (nexus.XXXX.com)... yyy.yy.yy.yy
Connecting to nexus.XXXX.com (nexus.XXXX.com)|yyy.yy.yy.yy|:80... failed: No route to host.`

Comment: Is your docker host placed in a private subnet inside the VPC?

Comment: @ashan. Yes it is.

Comment: Can you attach a Internet Gateway to router configuration in the subnet making it public and test. If it works then I can guide to setup a NAT gateway & etc to make it work i private subnet

Comment: Actually if I were to do the same setup on aws  and not install docker it works. I am able to replicate this on my mac too. Although I don't have wget on mac but a docker container built on mac host also cannot wget. It begs to say that both host and containers cannot retrieve the file.